# Is there Windows Media Center software of windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center

I am not sure if my question makes any sense, but I remember when I had Windows XP it came with Windows Media Center software.

Does Windows 7 have Windows Media Center?

Comment: From the tag description: "Windows Media Center is a Home Theater program that comes with most versions of Windows Vista and 7".  It's installed by default on 99% of systems...just search for it.

Comment: Windows Media Center is only available in Windows Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions

Comment: if this is not a real question then what is a real question?

Comment: It's not a real question because it shows a minimum of search effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Windows Media Center is included in Windows 7 Home Premium, Professional, and Ultimate editions.

[Microsoft source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-media-center/get-it)

To check if its installed go to: Control panel » Programs and features » Turn windows features on or off

[image]